# Spring MockMvc - How to test delete request of REST controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, mockito, spring-test-mvc

I need to test my controller methods including a delete method. Here is partial controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/foo")
public class FooController {

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    // other methods which works fine in tests

    @RequestMapping(path="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        fooService.delete(id);
    }    
}
```

And here is my test:

```
@InjectMocks
private FooController fooController;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(fooController)
.setControllerAdvice(new ExceptionHandler()).alwaysExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")).build();
}

@Test
public void testFooDelete() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .delete("/api/foo")
            .param("id", "11")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Test finish with failure because incorrect status code:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
>   Expected :200 Actual   :400

In console log I also found this:

```
2017-12-11 20:11:01 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name '' processing DELETE request for [/api/foo]
2017-12-11 20:11:01 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /api/foo
2017-12-11 20:11:01 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'DELETE' not supported
2017-12-11 20:11:01 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> cz.ita.javaee.web.controller.error.ExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception)
2017-12-11 20:11:01 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Written [{stackTrace=org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'DELETE' not supported
```

Can you tell me how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the param() method is equivalent to putting a path variable like the API has it, but I'm not sure.In other words, I think the call the test is doing is more like /api/foo?id=11 instead of /api/foo/11. This is just a guess, though.

Comment: @AHungerArtist I've changed it but same error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your target URI is: `/api/foo/11` based on this root: `/api/foo` and this path variable: `/{id}`.

When using `MockMvc` you set path variables (aka URI variables) like so:

```
delete(uri, uriVars)
```

More details [in the Javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#delete-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

So, your test should read:

```
@Test
public void testFooDelete() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .delete("/api/foo/{id}", "11")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
@Test
public void testFooDelete() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .delete("/api/foo/11")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is for sure correct :) But if you want to test the 204 response code:

```
@Test
public void testFooDelete() throws Exception {
    ...
    .andExpect(status().isNoContent());
}
```

you can explicitly say what should be returned by your delete method by using **@ResponseStatus**:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
    fooService.delete(id);
}
```